# Script shows no process found whereas it exist

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

Hi I've wrote this script and it is working but some of my processes shows as no process found

```
#!/bin/bash
OIFS=$IFS;
IFS=$'\n';
psC=$(ps -C "node" --format pid --no-headers)
arra=$(pwdx $psC)
array=($arra);
for ((i=0; i<${#array[@]}; ++i));
do
echo "$i: ${array[$i]}" 
done
```

I have attached the output as well

[image]

Comment: See [Bash FAQ 001](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) before trying to debug this any further.

Comment: `bash -x yourscript`, to get line-by-line logs (thus showing which commands are emitting which output), would also be a helpful place to start.

Comment: `declare -p array` is also a shorter way to print your array's contents (without needing the `for` loop).

Comment: Also, note that `IFS=$'\n'` still doesn't make assigning arrays via string splitting safe in the general case -- it disables string-splitting on non-newline fields, but doesn't disable glob expansion, so if you have a line containing `*`, it's replaced with a list of filenames in the current directory. Using `readarray`, `read -a`, or `mapfile` to populate arrays is more robust.

Comment: BTW, you just want to list the working directory for all your `node` processes? You could do that just through procfs, no `ps` or `pwdx` or other tools involved.

Comment: ...well, `ps` *does* make it easier: ```while read -r pid; do (cd "/proc/$pid/cwd" && pwd -P); done < <(ps -C "node" --format pid --no-headers)```

Comment: Thanks for this brief explanation. After running my script in debugging mode I came to know that IFS is making this error after commented the IFS everything works fine but now I got two separate indexes one for pid and other for path but it doesn't matter. Thanks